# Does "ass" mean something else than what I think it does?

Tags: meaning

The only meaning of "ass" I knew until today was the fleshy body part.

But what I read today on a shopping receipt shocked me. One of the items mentioned there was **Other ass**.

Surely that shop doesn't sell body parts. So does this word have some other meaning or is it just a spelling mistake?

Comment: *Ass* can mean a donkey-like animal. Or it could be an abbreviation for *assistant*, indicating you were served by someone whose real name isn't yet in the system to be available for printing. Is there any way you could provide more information (like a picture of your till receipt)?

Comment: If it is one of the items mentioned, I would assume it refers to _other assorted (goods)_ unless the store has the habit of selling assistants. I believe this is frowned upon in most modern societies...

Comment: Registered User, as you can see from this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ass_3 , *ass* only refers to a certain body part in the US. In the UK, the word is *arse*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - also bank details and pin if possible.  Note to Reg User , no only joking, really don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is of course the [animal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ass) but I doubt you bought one of those.

But I think the period after the *ass.* on your receipt is a clue. I have seen *ass.* (mind the period!) being used to mean *assortment*, *assorted*, en even *assistant*. (Yes, we have an ass. manager working here...).

On a receipt I would take it to mean *other assorted (goods)*.

Answer (score 0):

Ass also means "donkey". Hence we get words like "asinine" (donkey-like, i.e stupid). As an abbreviation, it most likely means "assistant".

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely that the OP bought either a donkey or an assistant at a store. There would be places where you can buy a donkey, but I would think the OP would have been aware if he bought one. Selling people, even assistants, is not only illegal, but considered morally wrong in most modern societies...

Comment: *Asinine* doesn't derive from *ass*, it derives from the Latin *asinus. Ass* is an Old English word with a coincidental resemblance, and the two are actually unrelated.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Next, you'll be saying that the claim that _donkey oats_ derives from the popular writings of Cervantes Saavedra is mere quixoticism.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - could you inform [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ass&searchmode=none) of their mistake? They _do_ see _ass_ as ultimately deriving from Latin _asinus_.

Comment: DV because this answer ignores the context of being printed on a shopping receipt.

Answer (score -4):

An ass could be a lion. Also it could be a flesh or a donkey. The donkey term refers to a dumb or foolish person. It never really meant anything else except for a lion according to some Bibles.

Comment: DV because this answer ignores the context of being printed on a shopping receipt.